# How to Convert date string to json date format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, wcf

In my application I am getting date in a string format like :
 var date="1988-11-4".
I am calling back the WCF service and sending data to the service as Json format. But my problem is the WCF service is only accepting the dates as {DoB:"/Date(570931200000+0530)/"} format.
can you please tell how do I convert date to json date format like:

var jasonDate="/Date(570931200000+0530)/". Where 570931200000 is the miliseconds calculated since from "1970-01-01" and +0530 is the Timezone.

Comment: What do you mean by json date format?

Comment: Please explain what you want exactly and what have you tried so far to achieve it.

Comment: @Andy I am sending date to a WCF service and it is accepting date format only as ""\/Date(1208559600000-0700)\/"" format. Can it be possible to convert a date string to the above format in Javascript.

Comment: @PrerakSola I want to send the date in json as "\/Date(1208559600000-0700)\/" format instead of "1988-05-03" . so it can be send as {"\/Date(1208559600000-0700)\/"}

Comment: How does `"1988-05-03"` relate to `"/Date(1208559600000-0700)/"`?

Comment: @ Xotic750 I am not sure exactly how the relation is but the WCF service sending me data like :
{"GetStockQuoteResult":
        {"Company":"MICROSOFT CP",
        "LastPrice":30.00,
        "LastQuoteTime":
        "\/Date(1208559600000-0700)\/",
        "LastQuoteTimeString":"Apr 18, 4:00PM",
        "NetChange":0.78,
        "OpenPrice":29.99,
        "Symbol":"MSFT"}
}

Comment: Best that you understand how they relate before posting the question.

Comment: How does "1988-05-03" relate to "/Date(1208559600000-0700)/"? - I think this is that 1988-05-03 is 1208559600000 ms since 1st Jan 1950 and the time zone is -0700 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a best guess, and to give you something to work with, until you understand what the relationship is and come back and explain things better along with what you have tried and the precise nature of the problem with your code.

```js
var dateTime = '1988-05-03',
    parts = dateTime.split('-'),
    date;

parts[1] -= 1;
date = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(null, parts));
document.body.textContent = '/Date(' + date.getTime() + '-0000)/';
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
var jsonDate = new Date(date).toJSON();
```

As the initial variable is only a string it would not be recognised as a date so create a date from it then convert that to JSON.

Comment: sorry, but is coverting to "2015-02-05T00:00:00.000Z" format. I need to convert it to "\/Date(1208559600000-0700)\/" format.

Comment: What do those parts mean? What is this `1208559600000` and this `-0700`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your response. I have got solution to my query. Here in the string "/Date(1208559600000-0700)/" 1208559600000 is the milliseconds calculated since from Jan 01 1970 and -700 is the time zone.

This the code that worked for me:

```
 convertToJsonDate: function (date) {
    var diff = date.getTime();
    var jsonDate = "\/Date(" + diff + "-0700)\/";
    return jsonDate;
},
```